# How to scale model.predict() as 100%

Tags: python, tensorflow

tensorflow model.predict() return classes result. I want to scale them as sum %100,

predict function:

`img = "./img/hat.jpg"`

```
def predict(img):
    img = preprocess_image(img)
    pred = model.predict(img)
    pred = np.squeeze(pred).astype(float)
    print(pred)
    return dict(zip(class_names, pred))
```

output

```
{'dress': -1.1803117990493774, 'hat': -3.3129501342773438, 'longsleee': -4.05311393737793, 'outwear': -3.61092472076416, 'pants': -1.313247561454773, 'shirt': -4.622654438018799, 'shoes': 13.270466804504395, 'shorts': -1.8179067373275757, 'skirt': -5.134970188140869, 't-shirt': -2.795290231704712}
```

I want to see hat: 0.98, shoes:0.003 etc.

Comment: That's not how it works.  It's telling you "these are shoes", and there is no match for the other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved  with

```
pred = np.squeeze(np.exp(pred)/np.sum(np.exp(pred))).astype(float)
```

now function is returning as percentage.

Comment: You could just use tf.nn.softmax and multiply with 100.